# Default MySQL user privileges after executing CREATE USER

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

What privileges does a newly created user have after running:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> creates a new row in the mysql.user table and assigns the account no privileges
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

Comment: I somehow missed that when I was reading the mysql docs. Thanks